# Div appearing in a different position in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I can't place a div in the same place in Firefox and in Chrome.
I have a div with these properties on my website (http://biabakery.site11.com/aboutbia.php):

```
#text3 {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: justify;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 480px;
    color: #EEE8AA;
}
```

It's the third text div called "The Store".
In Firefox it looks fine, but in Chrome it doesn't and I can't put it in the same position.

If I change `margin-left: 180px` in Chrome it's displayed as I want but not in Firefox.

Comment: I think you code is ok ...

Comment: post your code here. a fiddle helps for future users should your site change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change html architecture of your file, you can juste make repetetive div block like this :

```
<div class="block">
<div class="block-images"><img src="" /></div>
<div class="block-text"><p>Some Text....</p></div>
</div>
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9chi/27UL6/) exemple